# Get Remote Desktop on Redhat Enterprise linux. I have ssh access only

Tags: rhel, vnc, remote-desktop

I have ssh access on a Redhat enterprise Linux 7.3 machine with root privileges.
X-Manager is not serving my purpose to install some software.
I want to have remote desktop access on that machine.
Can anyone tell which packages do I need to install to get that working, 
and what would be the process to get remote desktop or vnc?

Comment: `ssh -X` will allow you to run X11 applications, if they are installed remotely, you are using an X11 server desktop, and it is not disabled. (they will appear in their own window, so full integration with current desktop)

Comment: @richard I have experienced the same problem as the user.  There are a number of configurations that I have problems getting to work using `ssh -X` .  As with the case of the OP, some X-Manager configurations will not provide the root root privileges without the user being logged in under X.  The only resolutions I found for those instances was to either use some remote desktop access or to have physical access to the computer.

Comment: AhmedRana, will you give an example of an application you're having problems with.  Some of the users might have an alternate resolution to that particular configuration without using a remove Desktop or `vnc`.

Comment: I am installing IBM Netcool, Impact and IBM Maximo on these machines. The X manager crashes during installation.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to install a VNC server on the remote computer and a VNC client on the client computer.

For the remote computer install **vino**.  For the client install **Vinagre**

Run this command on the server to configure the server:

```
$ vino-preferences
```

After you have configured the server, run this to connect:

```
$ vinagre
```